# Can't apt-get install, upload during speed test, or identify download server

Tags: networking

I'm having some networking problems that I can't figure out. I had Ubuntu 16.04 with these problems and just upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and they are persisting. The upgrade kept hanging (installing from Ubuntu Live ISO image on both USB and DVD). In the end I did the minimal install to finally get through. Unfortunately, after upgrading i found that my networking problems persisted.

I have multiple devices connected to my router. They are all working fine before and after a reboot. But, my Ubuntu machine continues to have problems.

Here is a summary of symptoms that I'm seeing.

1. I can browse the internet just fine. I'm writing this post from
   Firefox on the machine in question. I've loaded a large number of
   pages just fine.
2. `sudo apt-get update` also works fine.
3. `sudo apt-get install vim -y` fails with `0% [Waiting for headers]` Eventually (after a long time... 5 minutes?) I'll get

   ```
   Ign:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 vim-runtime all 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1
   ```

   and more of these if I wait long enough. What's odd is I can use firefox to connect to `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` just fine.
4. Opening **Software & Updates** and using the automatic *Select Best Server* option eventually fails saying

   > no suitable download server was found
5. My ISP is comcast. I ran [this speedtest](http://speedtest.xfinity.com/). I get great download speed results but the upload speed test completely fails and doesn't even give a result stating the test failed.

As I mentioned, I was seeing similar problems like this before the upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04. I did not keep as detailed of notes from before the upgrade... I had been wanting to upgrade for a while and naively hoped that a clean install would automagically fix things...

This machine is connected through a 100Mb/s hard wired connection. Wireless is completely off.

I'm stumped...

Comment: Can you manually download the package in question? Try running `wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim-runtime_8.0.1453-1ubuntu1_all.deb`. If this works, we need to look at `apt` instead of your network.

Comment: @Lienhart Woitok, unfortunately is fails... I get `wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim-runtime_8.0.1453-1ubuntu1_all.deb
--2018-06-04 19:34:20--  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim-runtime_8.0.1453-1ubuntu1_all.deb
Resolving us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.91.26, 91.189.91.23, 2001:67c:1562::19, ...
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.26|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... `  It's been stuck now for over 5 minutes...

Comment: Are you sure network is working? This looks like a network problem, but in your question you state, that you can browse the internet with firefox on the same machine. Can you download that url with firefox? If yes, can you download a url you can open with firefox using `wget`? I'm trying to determine whether this is a general network problem, a problem only existing outside firefox or a problem accessing this specific host or network.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by changing  your DNS. Comcast has been caught several times changing resolution entries... just because? I would definitely start there. Use OpenDNS ( 208.67.222.222 ) or google DNS (8.8.8.8)

Answer (score 0):

To ensure your Internet is working fine and also DNS resolution, do this:

> ```
> > ping -c 2 google.com
> 2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
> ```

If you have above output (0% packet loss), then you have Ok Internet connectivity, DNS resolution..
Now, you can re-run Step #4 in your Post
[Software & Updates > Download from: > Other > United States > Click: Select Best Server, and you should get it populated with a Server Example:
  http://es-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu
At which point, it will Message: "You should have a working Internet Connection" and start populating Cache.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I got 0% packet loss as you showed. However, the "Select Best Server" never selected a server. I manually selected one but when it tried to update the cache the GUI never returned. I manually performed a `sudo apt-get update` in the terminal and I'm now able to `sudo apt-get install <app>`. Not sure what happened but I can now install... Thanks all!

Comment: It should have popped another Window; Pressing ALT + TAB key will repeatedly take you to next Window that is Open; Complete Steps for "Software Updater" are given below; ensure you let that do your Updates.